# how to limit collision with multiple objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a mechanic. There is a player and an enemy. Each of them can attract cubes when touched. So when both touch the cube, the cube flies simultaneously to the enemy and the player, and I need it to fly to the first one who touched it.
This is what I have now

```cs
[SerializeField] private Transform _cube;
[SerializeField] private Transform _playerParent;
[SerializeField] private Transform _enemyParent;
private Transform _carPlayer, _carEnemy;
private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

private void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }


public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        _carPlayer = collider.transform;
    }

    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        _carEnemy = collider.transform;
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (_carPlayer)
    {
        PlayerTakeCube();
    }

    if (_carEnemyFirst)
    {
        EnemyFirstTakeCube();
    }
}

private void PlayerTakeCube()
{
    _cube.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, 
    _playerParent.position, 0.02f);
    _cube.transform.rotation = _playerParent.transform.rotation;
    _rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
    _cube.transform.SetParent(_playerParent);
}

private void EnemyFirstTakeCube()
{
    _cube.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, 
    _enemyParent.position, 0.02f);
    _cube.transform.rotation = _enemyParent.transform.rotation;
    _rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
    _cube.transform.SetParent(_enemyParent);
}
```

Comment: A bit unclear where `_playerParent` and `_enemyParent` come from and what exactly is supposed to happen .. but your code is quite redundant and you could have a single method and reuse it for both cases .. also you store the `_carPlayer` and `_carEnemy` references but never really use them ... Also is `_cube` the same as this object?

Comment: _playerParent and _enemyParent are Transforms into which cubes (_cube) should move, they are child objects of the car. I use _carPlayer and _carEnemy in FixedUpdate() to run PlayerTakeCube() and EnemyFirstTakeCube() methods. I need if someone was the first to touch the cube to that he will fly and he should no longer react to the second player.

Comment: Is `_cube` the same object this script is attached to? And is `_rigidbody` also on the `_cube` / the object this script is attached to?

Comment: Yes _cube, this is an object to which the script is attached and yes _rigidbody is on this object

Answer (score 0):

In OnTriggerEnter check if carPlayer or carEnemy is alredy assigned if so don't execute the rest:

I would also recommend to put the lines: 'rigidbody.isKinematic = true' and 'cube.transform.SetParent(...)' into the OnTriggerEnter method since you don't need to call this every FixedUpdate();

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    if(_carPlayer || _carEnemy) return; //Check if someone already took control
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        _carPlayer = collider.transform;
        _rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
        _cube.transform.SetParent(_playerParent);
    }
    
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        _carEnemy = collider.transform;
        _rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
        _cube.transform.SetParent(_enemyParent);
    }
}
```

The above example works only if you do not intend that the cubes can be stolen from each other.
If they can, I would say create a short timer for 1 second in which the cube can not be taken control of after someone touched it:

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    if(timer < 1) return;
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        _carPlayer = collider.transform;
        _rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
        _cube.transform.SetParent(_playerParent);
        timer = 0;
    }

    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        _carEnemy = collider.transform;
        _rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
        _cube.transform.SetParent(_enemyParent);
        timer = 0;
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if(timer < 1)
        timer += Time.fixedDeltaTime
    ...
}
```

Comment: The idea is that two cars each consist of cubes and when they collide, the cubes fly off (the car collapses) and you need to pick them up, each cube has its own transform, it flies to the car and stands on its transform, I inserted this line if (_carPlayer || _carEnemy) return ; and now they just fly behind the car.

Answer (score 0):

I would unify this a lot and simply have a component like e.g.

```
public class Car : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform CubeParent;
}
```

on both/all your cars.

Then you can simply do

```
private Car currentTarget;

public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    // Someone else was here before already 
    if(currentTarget) return;

    // Otherwise is this even a car at all?
    if(collider.TryGetComponent<Car>(out var car))
    {
        // If so get the parent object we should move to
        currentTarget = car;
        // make this kinematic
        _rigidbody.isKinematic = true;         
    }
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Only if _cube and currentTarget are both set
    if(_cube && currentTarget)
    {
        // Move the cube towards the target
        _cube.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(_cube.transform.position, currentTarget.CubeParent.position, 0.02f);
        _cube.transform.rotation = currentTarget.CubeParent.rotation;

        // If it reaches the position
        if(_cube.transform.position == currentTarget.CubeParent.position)
        {
            // parent it and forget the cube and target as no longer needed
            _cube.transform.SetParent(currentTarget.CubeParent);
            _cube = null;
            currentTarget = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you propose to create another script with a Car class? if so, then I did it and this line is currentTarget = car.CubeParent; gives an error message "cannot implicitly convert type UnityEngine.Transform in Car"

Comment: @RomanBabenko my bad, yeah the `currentTarget` should just be the `car` .. then you want to move towards the `currentTarget.CubeParent` instead