# how to smoothly resize an object once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a mechanic. two cars consisting of cubes (child objects of this car) in a collision, the cubes fall off (the car is destroyed) if you touch a cube lying on the floor, it starts to be attracted to this car and eventually becomes a child object of this car. When it falls into place, it should increase its size, then immediately decrease to its original size.I did this with the help of a coroutine, it works fine, but if you knock out the cube again, it becomes very huge. How to do it right?

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class DetachCube : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform _cube;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _playerParent;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _enemyParent;
    private Transform _carPlayer, _carEnemy;
    private bool _cubePickedUp = false;
    private Rigidbody _rigidbody;
    private Vector3 _newScaleCube = new Vector3(3, 3, 3);
    private Vector3 _oldScaleCube;

    private void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        _oldScaleCube = _cube.transform.localScale;
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Bumper")//"Bumper" - child object of auto that detaches cubes
        {
            _cube.parent = null;
            _rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
            _cubePickedUp = false;
        }

        if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Player car" && !_cubePickedUp)
        {
            _rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
            _cubePickedUp = true;
            _carPlayer = collider.transform;
        }

        else if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Enemy car 1" && !_cubePickedUp)
        {
            _rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
            _cubePickedUp = true;
            _carEnemy = collider.transform;
            _cube.transform.SetParent(_enemyParent);
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (_carPlayer)
        {
            Invoke("PlayerTakeCube", 0.4f);
            StartCoroutine(ScaleCube());
        }

        else if (_carEnemy)
        {
            Invoke("EnemyTakeCube", 0.4f);
            StartCoroutine(ScaleCube());
        }
    }

    private void PlayerTakeCube()
    {
        _cube.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, _playerParent.position, 0.04f);
        _cube.transform.rotation = _playerParent.transform.rotation;
        _cube.transform.SetParent(_playerParent);
    }

    private void EnemyTakeCube()
    {
        _cube.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, _enemyParent.position, 0.04f);
        _cube.transform.rotation = _enemyParent.transform.rotation;
        _cube.transform.SetParent(_enemyParent);
    }

    private IEnumerator ScaleCube()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        _cube.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale, _newScaleCube, 2 * Time.deltaTime);

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        _cube.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale, _oldScaleCube, 4 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you never reset `_carPlayer` then you keep starting hundreds of concurrent Coroutines ...

I would also not mix it with `Invoke` but rather use the routine so you are sure i finished scaling before you do some parenting.

Then there are multiple flaws I already flagged in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75557331/how-to-limit-collision-with-multiple-objects):

- If the `_cube` anyway refers to the same object this script is attached to just stick to `transform` directly, removes one source of confusion
- All you calls to `Vector3.MoveTowards` / `Vector3.Lerp` happen only **one single time** => There is no continous scaling using those

I would probably do

```
// Durations in seconds - ADJUST VIA INSPECTOR!
[SerializeField] private float scaleUpDuration = 0.5f;
[SerializeField] private float scaleBackDuration = 0.25f;

// If using option A below
// Absolute velocity in units per second - ADJUST VIA INSPECTOR
[SeriaizeField] private float moveToParentSpeed = 4f;

// If using option B below
[SerializeField] private float moveToParentDuration = 0.04f;

private bool _isPickedUp;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    if (collider.CompareTag("Bumper"))
    {
        // also interupt if currently in a picking up process?
        StopAllCoroutines();

        transform.parent = null;
        _rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
        _isPickedUp = false;
    }
    else if(!_isPickedUp)
    {
        var isPlayer = collider.CompareTag("Player car");
        var isEnemy = collider.CompareTag("Enemy car 1");

        if (isPlayer || isEnemy)
        {
            _isPickedUp = true;
            _rigidbody.isKinematic = true;

            // Start the routine ONCE in the moment of the event
            // There is no need at all to set fields and then poll check them in FixedUpdate
            StartCoroutine(ScaleCube(isPlayer ? _playerParent : _enemyParent));
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerator ScaleCube(Transform targetParent)
{  
    // This is an initial delay! Not sure if intended
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

    var originalScale = transform.localScale

    for(var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < scaleUpDuration; timePassed += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        // will linear grow from 0 to 1
        var factor = timePassed / scaleUpDuration;
        // [optional] add ease-in and -out
        factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, factor);

        // scale one interpolated step towards the target
        transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(originalScale, _newScaleCube, factor);

        // "pause" here, let this frame render 
        // and continue from here in the next frame
        yield return null;
    }
    
    // to be sure to end with clean values apply in the end
    transform.localScale = _newScaleCube;


    // again a delay
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);

    // scale back similar to see above
    
    for(var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < scaleBackDuation; timePassed += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        var factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, timePassed / scaleBackDuration);
        transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(_newScaleCube, originalScale, factor);
        yield return null;
    }

    transform.localScale = originalScale;

    // then also move towards the target parent.
    // there are two main options 
    // A) move with fixed velocity (might be an issue with moving target - might never reach if moving too slow)
    while(_cube.transform.position != _playerParent.position)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetParent.position, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        yield return null;
    }
    // OPTION B) Move with fixed duration like the scaling (works for moving targets without issues)
    var currentPosition = transform.position;
    for(var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < moveToParentDuration; timePassed += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        var factor = Mathf.SmoothStep(0, 1, timePassed / moveToParentDuration);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentPosition, targetParent.position, factor);

        yield return null;
    }

    // either way in the end apply 
    transform.position = targetParent.position;
    transform.rotation = targetParent.transform.rotation;
    transform.SetParent(targetParent);
}
```

And instead of having the hard references to `_playerParent` and `_enemyParent` I would probably still go through a common class as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75560995/7111561)

Comment: maybe, but my car consists of many transforms and the cube should move to one of them, and I use _playerParent and _enemyParent so that it understands which one to move to, but I'm sure that this is not correct and I still don't know how to improve it

Comment: as said you can have a common class which lists all the different parents .. then this can go to a specific one .. e.g. using an enum field or similar

Comment: I get an error on this variable "currentScale" in the first "WaitForSeconds", and I could not find in your script how we get it

Comment: @RomanBabenko `currentScale` -> `originalScale` .. missed to rename that one, `yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);` should be fine .. check for typos?

Comment: everything seems to be working, but for some reason the cubes decrease instead of increasing, and then after about a second they become very small, almost imperceptible.